# Format date using moment React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, date, momentjs, moment-timezone

I have created ** React Component**

```
class Test extends Component{

state = {
    birthdate: '2020-09-20'
}

render(){
    const {birthdate} = this.state;
    const mdiffInDays = moment(moment()).diff(moment(birthdate), 'days');
    const mdiffInWeeks = moment(moment()).diff(moment(birthdate), 'weeks');

    return(
    <div className="card">
        <span>Today: {moment(moment()).format('DD MMM YYYY')}</span>
        <span>Birthdate: {birthdate}</span>
        <span>Days: {mdiffInDays}</span>
        <span>Weeks: {mdiffInWeeks}</span>           
    </div>            
    )
}}
```

*I got two question:*

1. **Today** - how instead of `23-Oct-2020` I can use `"PL" region`?
2. **Birthdate** is render like: YYYY-MM-DD. How change this to **`display "DD-MM-YYY"`**?

I'm learning React and try to play now with dates.

Comment: If you want a different format why use `.format('DD MMM YYYY')` or `'2020-09-20'`?

Comment: You don't need moment js :) https://github.com/you-dont-need/You-Dont-Need-Momentjs

Comment: when I changed to '20-09-2020', into mdiffInDays Im getting values like -45

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const birthdate =  '2020-09-20'
const date = new Date(birthdate)
const options = {
  year: "numeric",
  month: "short",
  day: "numeric",
};
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString("pl", options));
```